# Closed operators and duality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces

Usually we would define a "densely defined, closed operator" on a Banach space $E$ to be a linear map $T:D(T)\rightarrow E$, where $D(T)$ is a dense subspace of $E$, and the graph of $T$, $G(T)=\{ (x,T(x)) : x\in D(T) \}$ is closed in $E\times E$.  Then we can define an adjoint by setting
`\[ D(T^*) = \{ f\in E^* : \exists g\in E^*, f(Tx) = g(x) \ (x\in D(T)) \}. \]`
That $D(T)$ is dense means that if $f\in D(T^*)$ then the associated $g$ is unique, so we can define $T^*(f)=g$.  This level of generality seems rare-- e.g. Davies in his book "One-parameter semigroups" mentions this, notes that $D(T^*)$ can fail to be norm dense, and moves on to Hilbert spaces.

Indeed, most books seem to just start out working with Hilbert spaces (and then usually $T^*$ means the Hilbert space adjoint-- but this is essentially the same thing, up to twisting by some conjugation).  Here you can apply Hilbert space techniques to show that $D(T^*)$ is dense etc.

It seems to me however that $D(T^*)$ will always at least be weak$^*$-dense and that $G(T^*)$ will be weak$^*$-closed in $E^*\times E^*$.  Moreover, the proofs don't seem to need Hilbert space techniques.  Moreover, starting with such a "weak$^*$-closed, densely defined operator" on $E^*$, we can always find a densely-defined closed operator on $E$ which induces it.  Applied to a reflexive Banach space, one builds a very satisfactory theory.

The only source I know which talks about "closed" operators in such generality is a paper by Ciorănescu and Zsidó, see [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0430867) or [Project Euclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178240775).  Even they don't mention the duality result.

> My question: Is there a good (or even bad) reference for all this?  In particular, that a weak$^*$-closed operator is the adjoint of a closed operator?

Comment: The first two books I pulled from my shelf do unbounded operator theory in the context of Banach spaces.  They are the obscure :) books
Dunford & Schwartz and Pazy's "Semigroups of linear operators and applications to partial differential equations".  I recall that Kato also does much of the theory in Banach spaces.

I did not try to check whether D-S or Pazy state the specific facts you noted. I think Pazy usually specializes to the case of reflexive spaces when duality plays an important role.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for those suggestions.  Kato, Chapter III Section 5 gets very close to what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See \S 36 of 
G. K\"{o}the: Topological Vector Spaces, Vol. 2

Comment: This almost does it in too much detail; but it's a pretty good reference.  Thanks!